# How can I center an image between two other images in this example?

Tags: css

I have a div 'imgcontainer' and a div 'commentcontainer'.  Representing a large image and a white box filled with comments below.  I want to add a third image that sits on top of the two, vertically centered.

So basically what I'm trying to do is this: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/488816/screenshots/1726057/1_1x.jpg

My problem is that I can't figure out how to integrate the CSS to do this into my code below.  What can I add to the 'profilepic' div in order to set that image to sit midway between the imgcontainer and commentcontainer ?

## HTML

```
<div id="timeline">
            <div class="block2x3 block">
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                    <img src="top-picture.jpg" />

                    <div class="profilepic">
                    <img src="facepic.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="commentcontainer">
                    <div class="peoples">
                        <a href="#"><strong class="people name">Joe Schmoe</strong></a> and <a href="#">42 other people bought this</a>
                        <p>Have commented on your <a href="#">wall post</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

## CSS3

```
@media (max-width:1860px) { 
#timeline .block .imgcontainer img  {width:100%;}
#timeline div[class*="block"][class*="x1"]  {height:150px;}
#timeline div[class*="block"][class*="x2"]  {height:300px;}
#timeline div[class*="block"][class*="x3"]  {height:450px;}
#timeline div[class*="block2x3"] .imgcontainer  {height:60%; position:relative; z-index:1;}
#timeline div[class*="block2x3"] .commentcontainer  {height:40%; z-index:2;}


.profilepic {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 7px solid white;
    border-radius: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your CSS to center the 'profile' pic you can add this to you CSS:

```
.profilepic {
    /*margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;  INSTED OF THIS */
    margin-left: auto;  /* USE  */
    margin-right: auto; /* THIS */
    border: 7px solid white;
    border-radius: 70px;
}
```

but first you will have to add this to you css file:

```
html  { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Hope it works :')